# Select option from the drop down list and display in table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list and submit button along with table header called fruits

For example: If I select one of the option from the drop down list and by clicking the submit button. The selected option from the list, should display in table cell.

Could some one help me to resolve the issue that would be grateful.

Here is code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnGet").click(function() {
    var selectedText = $("#ddlFruits").find("option:selected").text();
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = selectedText;
    row++;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlFruits">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Submit" />

<table id="display">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruits</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Start by checking what the browser’s error console has to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the script.Please try this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        var selectedText = $("#ddlFruits").find("option:selected").text();
        if(selectedText!="None"){
            var display = document.getElementById("display");
             $('#display tr:last').after('<tr><th>'+selectedText+'</th></tr>');
        }



    });
});
```

Comment: Wooooooooow :) :)  Superb its working too  great job:) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work,

```
$(function () {
      $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        var selectedText = $("#ddlFruits").find("option:selected").text();
        var display = document.getElementById("display");
        var newRow = display.insertRow(display.rows.length);
        var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = selectedText;
      });
    });
```